# FILE* access violation

Tags: c++

I have an annoying access violation problem with Visual Studio 2012. I had the same problem in Visual Studio 2010 and I thought that it could be a compiler problem but it turns out it is not.

Here is part of the code that gives me the access violation:

```
SDL_Surface *cGraphicsManager::LoadImageFromPak(char *filename, char *img_type)
{
    // Load the 'file' to SDL_Surface

    SDL_Surface *img = NULL;    
    char errorname[50];
    sprintf(errorname, "Unable to load image %s from pakfile", filename);

    FILE *fin = pakfile.open_file(filename);
    if(!fin)
    {
        ErrorLog(errorname);
        return NULL;
    }

    SDL_RWops *rw;
    rw = SDL_RWFromFP(fin, 1);
    if (!rw)
    {
        ErrorLog("Erro na linha 213");
        return NULL;
    }

    img = IMG_LoadTyped_RW(rw,0, img_type);  // it crashes on this line
    if(img == NULL)
        ErrorLog("Unable to load image from pakfile.");
    SDL_FreeRW(rw);
    //pakfile.close_mpk();
    //if (img_type == "PNG")
    img = add_transparency(img);
    return img;
}
```

It gives me access violation writing at location 0x00000014.
The weird thing is that it compiles and runs fine on MingW compiler, which makes me think that it is not wrong code.
I read something about a problem with File* and Dll calls but I didnt find how to fix that.
I have no linking warnings and I have linked all necesary libs. I am also running it in debug mode and compiling in multi-threaded debug dll (MDd).
Visual studio is much faster for writing code and easier for debugging than MingW and I would appreciate any response.
Thank you very much.

Comment: OK, so which line of code is generating the exception???

Comment: You might have less trouble if you actually used C++ instead of C with classes.

Comment: What is the value of `img_type` when it crashes?

Comment: @OldProgrammer OP notes the crashing line in his sample

Answer (score 2):

The address is telling - the code is dereferencing a null pointer to access a member that's `0x14 (20)` bytes from the object address.  I would sniff around the contents of the `rw` parameter.  It may not be null, but may contain a member that is.  I'd also seriously recommend using a debugger which will halt on the crash so you can inspect the call stack.  One last suggestion - if you're using a third-party library, it may need some kind of initialization call to set up global state.  Failure to do this might cause a crash (personal experience).

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback. As requested, img_type is "PNG"  at call time. I also agree with the comment that I should not mix C and C++ code but the only examples from reading files from packfiles used SDL_Rwops for that and it uses C code. Also, rw seems to be corrupted indeed. The compiler tells that cannot load sdl symbols for its members. I really think it is some kind of initialization problem as mentioned because it runs fine on MingW compiler. Thanks for all help guys!